# SDL Web8 with DXA 1.6: How can we implement simplest personalization on a web page created on using SDL Web8 with DXA 1.6

Tags: web8, dxa, personalization, dxa-1.6

What is the simplest way to implement the personalization on a web page when the web page has been implemented using SDL web8 and DXA 1.6 combination. We just need a basic implementation not a complexed one like using smart target.

I checked the Profiling and Personalization section explained in docs.sdl.com which explain about using Tracking Keys and in that it ask to update the cd_wai_conf.xml on the presentation server. In my web application which is created on SDL Web8 with DXA I do not find this cd_wai_conf.xml file so I am not sure the same approach will work here in my case or not. Please share your ideas on same; thanks

Comment: Why do you think SmartTarget is too complex? DXA comes with support for it out-of-the-box. And you can have Fredhopper hosted in the cloud so you don't even have to worry about maintaining that either. It really is the best personalization solution we provide, in my opinion.

Comment: @PeterKjaer, thanks for your comment. The present need is to showcase a quick demo on personalization in SDL Web8+DXA to our client, can you share some reference link on this that shows steps how  to implement this in a quick time; we do not want a heavy implementation for this showcase and which ever option can be quickly implemented we prefer that at present.

Comment: What are your requirements. even P&P is not supported CD part of DXA. you have to implement your logic.

Comment: @Gulshan are you an SDL Partner? We can provide our pre-configured demo system which runs on Web 8 and DXA and has Experience Optimization / targeting configured and running if it helps with your demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Personalization and Profiling functionality is considered legacy and is not available in the SDL Web 8 CIL API.

You can use conditional Component Presentations based on Context Expressions using the DXA Context Expressions Module.

You can also use Experience Optimization (a.k.a. SmartTarget) using the DXA Experience Optimization Module.

Comment: Thanks for giving direction, I prefer to use option "use conditional Component Presentations based on Context Expressions using the DXA Context Expressions Module". Is there any reference material, guide, samples available which can provide details on steps to implement this in .Net webapplication based on SDLWEb8 + DXA 1.6

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6/GUID-DB75A02E-1BAD-4720-A123-41D46334AEEC

Comment: Hi Rick; i have already check this link it only shows how to execute installations script and set context expression script, Nothing more relevant details it has to help end to end implementation

Comment: The idea is that once you have properly installed and configured everything, created Target Groups with Context Expressions (according to docs) and use these Target Groups as conditions on your Component Presentations in CM, the DXA CX Module will ensure these CX conditions get evaluated and CPs/Entities which don't meet the conditions will be suppressed.

Comment: Hi Rick; SDL web8 documentation says "Note that for the Context Expression Extension to work, you must have an integration with CMA set up for your Content Manager". Is this really required ?The target group i created in cms at present show only definition tab. http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-B047B9AC-64A0-4263-9E46-181B7875C91A#docid=GUID-B047B9AC-64A0-4263-9E46-181B7875C91A&filename=GUID-B047B9AC-64A0-4263-9E46-181B7875C91A.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-B047B9AC-64A0-4263-9E46-181B7875C91A

Comment: I found this Article on PnP http://blog.building-blocks.com/technical-tips/how-to-setup-sdl-tridion-profiling-personalisation. the approach it uses is to use Tracking keys and Target Groups which I do prefer and most interested to use it. In this article CMS steps mentioned are fine but for the steps on Presentation server I have doubt because I am using DXA 1.6 framework to render the webpages also the CP are embedded on Page in my case. I did not find any cd_wai_conf.xml in my web application folders.

Comment: As said, legacy P&P is not supported in SDL Web 8 CIL (on which DXA builds). Regarding Context Expressions: the DXA Module ships with a PowerShell script which you can use to set the CX in CM.